# Django Ajax 'GET'

Tags: ajax, django

newbie here. I am trying to get some data from my database using ajax.

In my views.py,

```
def getEvents(request):
    eventList = Events.objects.all()
    events=[]
    for event in eventList:
        events.append({"name": event.name, "start": event.start, "end": event.end})
    return HttpResponse(events, content_type="application/json")
```

Note that `Events` is the `model` that I am trying to parse. After I collect the data from this model, I want to return it to my template using the following ajax code:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getEvents/',
                datatype: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                sucess: function(data) {
                    alert(data.name);
                }
            });
```

In my urls.py:

```
url(r'^getEvents/', views.getEvents, name='getEvents'),
```

However, I think I am doing something wrong because it doesn't work. I have been stuck on this for hours...Any ideas?

EDIT:

Okay. When I append the `getEvents` to the url, I do see all the database objects together in a dict but it seems my `ajax` is not working. How do I parse this data? The data is in the form:

```
[{"start": "2017-02-06", "end": "2017-02-07", "name": "Capstone Meeting"},
{"start": "2017-02-07T0:00", "end": "2017-02-08", "name": "Capstone"}, 
{"start": "2017-01-31T0:00", "end": "2017-02-01", "name": "dasdsd"}, 
{"start": "2017-01-31", "end": "2017-02-01", "name": "hjb"}]
```

Here is what I have so far...

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getEvents/',
                datatype: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                sucess: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                        $('body').append($('<div>', {
                            text: element.name
                        }));
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: What about your code doesn’t work?  Which part is failing.  Are there any error messages?

Comment: The alert doesn't pop up.

Comment: Have you tried setting the endpoint to `/getEvents/`?

Comment: Also, have you tested to see if the getEvents endpoint is working and returning the expected response?

Comment: Yes, if i append getEvents to my url, I can see the database objects. [{"start": "2017-02-06", "end": "2017-02-07", "name": "Capstone Meeting"}, {"start": "2017-02-07T0:00", "end": "2017-02-08", "name": "Capstone"}, {"start": "2017-01-31T0:00", "end": "2017-02-01", "name": "dasdsd"}, {"start": "2017-01-31", "end": "2017-02-01", "name": "hjb"}]. So they are stored in a dict as expected. I was wondering, how i can parse these values?

Answer (score 1):

One of your errors is being caused by not using a [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) in your view instead of an `HttpResponse`.  Here’s how to fix that issue:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def getEvents(request):
    eventList = Events.objects.all()
    events=[]
    for event in eventList:
        events.append({"name": event.name, "start": event.start, "end": event.end})
    return JsonResponse(events)
```

From the docs, the `JsonResponse` is

> An `HttpResponse` subclass that helps to create a JSON-encoded response.

The reason that your regular `HttpResponse` didn’t work, is because you have to manually serialize the data to JSON when using an `HttpResponse`, e.g., something like:

```
import json

response_data = json.dumps(events)
return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

Otherwise, I think what will happen is that you will get a call to `__repr__` on the events list which will get you python ast serialized data and not JSON serialized data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's a typo of your `sucess` function, it should be `success`.

Secondly, JSON response should be a dict object rather than a list, if you really want to get a JSON array response anyway, then you have to specify `safe=False` when you serializing the data by using `JsonResponse(events, safe=False)`, otherwise you'll get a `TypeError` like `TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False`.

So the code sample should be:

```
def getEvents(request):
    eventList = Events.objects.all().values("name", "start", "end")
    return JsonResponse({"events": eventList})
```

And for frontend:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getEvents/',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.events, function(index, element) {
                    $('body').append($('<div>', {
                        text: element.name
                    }));
                });
            }
        });
```